# Query XML data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am relatively new to SQL Server. Currently I am working with a table that has a XML column in it and I want to extract values from this column. I have tried multiple ways shared in Stackoverflow but none of them seem to be working for me. Can you guys help me with the solution?

DB version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3)

Sample data:

```
<r>
    <SerialisedEvent>
        BEGIN:VEVENT
        ATTENDEE:mailto:3ab162bc-4721-4fc2-94da-86aee8ee79e6
        DESCRIPTION:Review status of infection
        DTEND:20190701T180000
        DTSTAMP:20190624T140113
        DTSTART:20190701T080000
        LOCATION:
        SEQUENCE:0
        UID:08376c46-7fae-4073-b41e-03cb4cdbb008
        END:VEVENT
    </SerialisedEvent>
</r>
<r>
    <SerialisedEvent>
        BEGIN:VEVENT
        ATTENDEE:mailto:3ab162bc-4721-4fc2-94da-86aee8ee79e6
        DESCRIPTION:Review status of infection
        DTEND:20191025T180000
        DTSTAMP:20191018T102124
        DTSTART:20191025T080000
        LOCATION:
        SEQUENCE:0
        UID:ccdf6200-097a-401f-997b-7fb6aa170cdb
        END:VEVENT
    </SerialisedEvent>
</r>
```

Desired output:

```
 BEGIN | ATTENDEE | DESCRIPTION | DTEND ....
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please **show us** what **YOU** have tried so far! We'll be glad to help - but we won't just write the whole code for you .....

Comment: The content of the `SerializedEvent` element is a single string.  No XML parser will help you extract the parts of it.  You'll need to find the specification for how it's constructed and write custom code to extract the individual components.

Comment: Thanks friends for your quick replies. I can understand now why none of XML parser worked. I will write my own program now.

Answer (score 0):

not very clean (or safe) but doable

```
declare @x xml = N'<r>
    <SerialisedEvent>
        BEGIN:VEVENT1
        ATTENDEE:mailto:3ab162bc-4721-4fc2-94da-86aee8ee79eA
        DESCRIPTION:Review status of infection 1
        DTEND:20190701T180000
        DTSTAMP:20190624T140113
        DTSTART:20190701T080000
        LOCATION:
        SEQUENCE:0
        UID:08376c46-7fae-4073-b41e-03cb4cdbb008
        END:VEVENT1
    </SerialisedEvent>
</r>
<r>
    <SerialisedEvent>
        BEGIN:VEVENT2
        ATTENDEE:mailto:3ab162bc-4721-4fc2-94da-86aee8ee79eB
        DESCRIPTION:Review status of infection 2
        DTEND:20191025T180000
        DTSTAMP:20191018T102124
        DTSTART:20191025T080000
        LOCATION:
        SEQUENCE:0
        UID:ccdf6200-097a-401f-997b-7fb6aa170cdb
        END:VEVENT2
    </SerialisedEvent>
</r>'

select @x


select *
from
(
select rownum, 
    e.el, substring(t.textvalue, charindex(e.el, t.textvalue)+len(e.el)+1, charindex(char(10), t.textvalue, charindex(e.el, t.textvalue))-charindex(e.el, t.textvalue)-len(e.el)-1) as thevalue
from
(
select 
    replace(n.e.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(8000)'), char(13), char(10)) as textvalue, 
    row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rownum
from @x.nodes('r/SerialisedEvent') as n(e)
) as t
cross apply (values('BEGIN'),('ATTENDEE'), ('DESCRIPTION'), ('DTSTAMP'), /*(...)*/ ('UID')) as e(el)
) as src
pivot
(
max(thevalue) for el in ([BEGIN], [ATTENDEE], [DESCRIPTION], [DTSTAMP], /*(...)*/ [UID])
) as unp;
```